I am unable to filter data in many to many relationship in sequelize
I have three tables/models in sequelize, Teachers, Classes, and Divisions. I have established many to many relationship between Teachers and Divisions. and One to Many relationship between Classes and Divisions.
I am fetching data from database like this:
const data = await TProfile.findAll({
        where: {},
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            attributes: ["uuid", "name", "email", "mobile"],
          },
          {
            model: Division,
            include: Klass,
            attributes: ["classId", "divisionId", "divisionName"],
          },
        ],
      });

Now, I want to filter data based on classId and divisionId. Something like this:
const data = await TProfile.findAll({
        where: {},
        include: [
          {
            model: User,
            attributes: ["uuid", "name", "email", "mobile"],
          },
          {
            model: Division,
            where: { divisionId }
            include: {
              model: Klass,
              where: { classId }
            },
            attributes: ["classId", "divisionId", "divisionName"],
          },
        ],
      });

divisionId and classId both are optional.
When I am trying to filter with divisionId i.e. where: { divisionId }, I am getting error Unknown column 'Teacher.divisionId' in 'where clause', and when doing same with klassid i.e. where: { classId }  getting same error Unknown column 'Teacher.classId' in 'where clause'
Is there anyother way to do same like this?
When I am fetching through Division, I am able to filter based on divisionId though I am not getting results as structured when fetching through Teacher model and not able to found a way to get teachers associated with class.
I also tried using approach where I can fetch Classes, Divisions and then Teachers but that's also not working.
Is there any suggestion to do this better?

please share your table creation code as well

Please add model definitions and all associations. Also you didn't mention how are linked TProfile and User between them and among other models.
